# Deploying the AWS lambda from VS Code: ValidationError in DescribeStacks - must satisfy regular expression

Tags: aws-lambda

1. Coded an AWS lambda function in Python3.12 on my local VS Code.
2. Successful with `$ sam build` and `$ sam local invoke`
3. An error encountered at the `$ sam deploy --guided` step. The error is:

```
Error: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeStacks operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'lambda-python3.12-fa47e7c4-CompanionStack' at 'stackName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*|arn:[-a-zA-Z0-9:/._+]*
```

I'm looking for a quick-fix resolution to this error and the lambda to get deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this note that the stack name `lambda-python3.12` does not satisfy the regular expression pattern given. The decimal in 3.12 does not fit the pattern.
For a quick fix, redo the `$ sam deploy --guided` again, but this time for the answer to `Stack Name [lambda-python3.12]:` don't just accept the default, rather change to `lambda-python3` and move on with the rest.
Good luck!